# How to get string in path from split?

Tags: javascript, jquery

it didn't work on stackoverflow snippet but if you try on your local you will see it's going to work.

js give me a this result

```
cdn=//cdn.files.com/web
```

but I dont want to this line

```
cdn=
```

js must give me after from `cdn=` I mean result must be like this

```
//cdn.files.com/web
```

my all js is below so how to do that ?

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var index = scripts.length - 1;
var myScript = scripts[index];
// myScript now contains our script object
var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\=]+\??/,'');

alert(decodeURIComponent(queryString));
```

```html
<script src="//domain.com/web/Assets/js/main.js?cdn=%2f%2fcdn.files.com%2fweb"></script>

<p></p>
```

Comment: why can't you use `^.+?cdn=` in your regex? `var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^.+?cdn=/,'');` this will give you strings after the `cdn=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
       var s = "cdn=//cdn.files.com/web";
     
       s2 = s.substring(s.indexOf("cdn=")+4,s.length);
    
       alert(s2);
```

this will substring from the index next to equals character to the end of yours string :)

fixed and tested

Comment: @ani_css could you set an answer as best answer? i´m new to the community

Answer (score 2):

Split the string by `'?cdn='` and get the part after that(second element in the result array, at index `1`).

```
var queryString = myScript.src.split('?cdn=')[1];
```

---

**FYI :** If there is only one URL param then you can simply use `=` or `cdn=` for splitting.

Comment: it's work very well I'd like to very much so can we use like this=`split('=')[1];` I mean after from `=` it's working like this too but can be any problem ?

Comment: @ani_css : it will work... in case if there are multiple url params it may cause problems

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
yourvariable.split('=');
```

So whatever your arguments into GET, the **odd** param will get your desired result.

PS: Prefer just the = char, because you can work with whatever param you want into link gived by src.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with regex

```js
var src = 'cdn=//cdn.files.com/web';
var url = src.replace(/^([^\=]+=)(.*)$/, '$2');
console.log(decodeURIComponent(url));
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VmQCdp/3) with explanation

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

why can't you use `^.+?cdn=` in your regex?

this will give you strings after the `cdn=`

```js
var myScript = '//domain.com/web/Assets/js/main.js?cdn=%2f%2fcdn.files.com%2fweb';
var queryString = myScript.replace(/^.+?cdn=/, '');
console.log(decodeURIComponent(queryString));
```